# Robot Localization GPS go down

Tags: navigation, gps, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the robot_localization package. The first ekf node to fuse odometry and IMU data. The second ekf node to fuse odometry, navsat_node output and IMU data. I use datum parameter in navsat's roslaunch to create a fixed transform between map and odom.

The first problem is that this transformation doesn't remain fixed.

The second question is: if i lose the GPS signal, the second kalman filter continues an open loop position estimation in map frame or gives the same output of the first ekf?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228440/robot-localization-gps-go-down/) by [Niko](https://answers.ros.org/users/25510/niko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The datum parameter creates a fixed transform between the UTM grid and your world frame, not between *map* and *odom*. If your robot moves in the *map* or *odom* frame, then the transform between them will not be fixed. A fixed transform between *map* and *odom* means that your pose estimate in both frames is identical, which would almost never be the case.

If you lose GPS signal, then yes, you will continue to get a state estimate in your *map* instance of the EKF using just the odometry and IMU data. Redundancy is one of the key benefits of fusing multiple sources.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Niko](https://answers.ros.org/users/25510/niko/) on 2016-03-08**:
thank you so much. I thought that datum gave a fixed transform between map and odom but now the problem will be solved. :)